# Will motherboard SSI CEB fit into EATX case with ATX PSU?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, case

I am building Dual-Xeon PC system.

Motherboard is SSI CEB form factor. I want to know, do I have to find specifically SSI CEB case or just the standard EATX would do.

I heard people saying "it fill ***fit***", because EATX is bigger than SSI CEB, and screwing points are the same, but my biggest concern is the power. Somebody said that SSI is power supply standart, so ATX PSU won't work.

Do I have to buy SSI-based PSU to fit it in EATX case? Or usual ATX PSU would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, the main difference is the power supply standard.

The ATX powersupply connectors will fit, but the locking clips may not align.

That main reason they made a different standard for the SSI form factor is to support the increased power requirements of dual-CPU systems, so as long as you use a high-quality power supply that puts out enough power to correctly drive ALL of the components you'll install in the computer, and figure out how to get the clips to work, you should be OK.

Comment: Can you exactly clarify what locking clips are? Image URL would be great.

Comment: I'm working to find an image now. I recall seeing a diagram when I first saw this question (a little Googling is what really answered your question) but cannot find it at this moment. If you're familiar with building a PC, you may remember a clip on the primary power connector(s) which clips to a lip in the mainboard socket. On the SSI CEB standard this clip is in a different location, so depending on the overall design, your main power cables may not actually lock to their sockets on the mainboard.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much! If you find that diagram, that would be very cool, but nevertheless, thanks :)

Comment: I spent a bit of time yesterday looking for it but simple cannot find it ATM. I'll look a bit more later.